# Naming REST API - Get collections of non-member attributes

Tags: api, rest

Let's say that I'm developing an application about shopping. I have defined the following endpoints, which are quite self-explanatory:

```
GET /items
GET /items/{item-id}
GET /stores
GET /stores/{store-id}
```

Now, I want to create another endpoint that displays the price of individual item at different stores. This price information is not included in `/items/{item-id}` since I don't think it's suitable to be an attribute of item, and getting the list of prices requires a bit more calculation as I cannot return the object directly. I will name the endpoint `/items/{item-id}/prices` and expect a response like this:

```
[
  {
    "store_id": "store_1",
    "price": 13.00
  },
  {
    "store_id": "store_2",
    "price": 12.99
  }
]
```

I want to extend this further and create another endpoint that returns the price information for all items, but I'm having trouble naming this endpoint. So far I've thought of `/items/prices` or `/items?display=prices` but the former might be confusing as it matches with `/items/{item-id}`, and the latter just.. does not seem to make sense for me.

What is the best name to pick for my endpoint so that it stays consistent with the convention?

Answer (score 1):

For all items pricelist endpoint for a single store, I'd recommend `GET /stores/{store-id}/prices` or `GET /stores/{store-id}/pricelist`.

For all items/stores pricelist, I'd use `GET /items/pricelist` or `GET /items/*/pricelist`, (both special before `/items/{item-id}`), which could be store-specified on demand by `?store={store-id}`.

Answer (score 1):

Adding prices endpoint to items would make no sense as item itself has nothing to do. It is store's responsibility to dictate the price.

I would suggest renaming stores endpoint to `/stores/description/{id}` and adding prices subcategory `/stores/prices/by-item/{id}` and `/stores/prices/by-store/{id}`.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that for sepecfic item **/prices/{store-id}/{item-id}**
and for all prices **/prices/{store-id}**